# Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am receiving this error in XCode 6.3.2:

> Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)

I have tried `for (int prob = 0; prob < response; prob++)` and received the same error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned seed;
    int randa, randb, answer, correct;

    seed = static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0));
    srand(seed);

    while (true)
    {
        int response = ' ';
        cout << "How many equations would you like to do? \n";
        cin >> response;

        for (int prob = response; prob > 0; prob--)
        {
            cout << "Calculate the following equation: \n";
            correct = rand() % 100 + 0;
            randa = correct - rand() % correct + 0;
            randb = correct - randa;
            cout << randa << " + " << randb << " = ";
            cin  >> answer;
            if (answer == correct)
            {
                cout << "Correct!\n";

            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Incorrect. The correct answer is: " << correct << "\n";
            }


            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried two different compilers (Windows/MSVC and Linux/g++) ... and I don't get that warning.

However - you're doing a "return 0" from your loop.

Which, of course, defeats the purpose of having a loop :)

And also happens to terminate your program.

Move the "return" outside of the loop, and Life should be Good :)

Answer (score 4):

Move this line:

```
return 0;
```

It will end the loop (function as well as program!).