# C++: Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)

Tags: c++, list, oop

I know there is a topic [Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747607/loop-will-run-at-most-once-loop-increment-never-executed), but it does not answear my question.

I have following code:

```
class Station{
public:
    Station();
    void addWartezimmer(Wartezimmer wartezimmer);
    void addBehandlungszimmer(Behandlungszimmer behandlungszimmer);
    int getWartezimmer();
private:
    list<Wartezimmer> WartezimmerListe;
    list<Behandlungszimmer> BehandlungszimmerListe;
};

Station::Station(){
    
}

void Station::addWartezimmer(Wartezimmer wartezimmer){
    this->WartezimmerListe.push_back(wartezimmer);
}

void Station::addBehandlungszimmer(Behandlungszimmer behandlungszimmer){
    this->BehandlungszimmerListe.push_back(behandlungszimmer);
}

int Station::getWartezimmer(){
    list<Wartezimmer>::iterator i;
    for (i = WartezimmerListe.begin(); i != WartezimmerListe.end(); i++){
        
    return  i->getAnzahlPlaetze();
    
    }
   
    return 0;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Zimmer zimmer("05.23");
    
    Wartezimmer WarteZimmer1(12, "01.12");
    Wartezimmer WarteZimmer2(14, "03.12");
    
    Behandlungszimmer Behandlungszimmer1("Intensiv", "01.01");
    
    Station West;
    West.addWartezimmer(WarteZimmer1);
    West.addWartezimmer(WarteZimmer2);
    West.addBehandlungszimmer(Behandlungszimmer1);
    
    
    cout << West.getWartezimmer();
}
```

If I execute this command, it will be printed "12". I expect "1214", because there are two Objects which have Numbers.

If I change the function to void and print it in the function, it is "1214".

```
void  Station::getWartezimmer(){
    list<Wartezimmer>::iterator i;
    for (i = WartezimmerListe.begin(); i != WartezimmerListe.end(); i++){
        
    cout <<   i->getAnzahlPlaetze();
    
    }
   

};
```

So my specific Question: How can I return a value of a function, if it is more than one value from a list? I don´t want only "12", I want "1214" because they are 2 Objects.

Comment: The title of your question seems to bear no relation to what you are actually asking about.  Could you fix that please?

Comment: Do you want the string `"1214"`, or the integer `1214`, or do you want the sum (`26`), or do you want a `std::vector<int>` to be returned? Why is the function called `getWartezimmer()` when it returns the number of places available in wait rooms? Maybe something like `getAnzahlWartezimmerplaetze()` might be better.

Comment: @PaulSanders it has something to do with it, bacuse Xcode returns this as the error message,why I cant get the whole data...

Comment: @Mark Baumann you can't get whole data because you call return on first element in the loop and what you return is a single int not the vector or list of ints.

Comment: @G.Sliepen First Things first. I don`t care if It is a String or a Integer Method. I don´t want to give a vector back. I did´t say anything about vectors......If you have any idea to give the whole data back, please write it. again, for me it is not important if it is a string or a int. I only want the whole data "1214" and not only "12"

Comment: @MonteChrist0 can you give me a answear how it should be? I am in the Loop of a list?

Comment: Your question is "how do I return multiple values from a function?" For starters, the return type of your function has to *support* multiple values. The current return type is `int`; you can't store two integers in a single `int`. If you want to return multiple items, you could indeed return an entire list (or some other container object). You could also pass a container by reference and append the results to that container, treating it as the output of the function. But keep in mind that exposing the underlying container through `Station::getWartezimmer` is probably poor encapsulation.

Comment: Ok than I wan´t to return the List with the values of getAnzahlplaetze().

Comment: how should be the datatype of the function?

Comment: Check my answer I guess it's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get whole data you could change int getWartezimmer(); to

```
list<Wartezimmer> Station::getWartezimmer()
{
   return WartezimmerListe;
}
```

but I guess you want AnzahlPlaetze whatever it is so int getWartezimmer you could simply do this

```
vector<AnzahlPlaetze> Station::getWartezimmer()
{
   vector<AnzahlPlaetze> result;
   for(const auto& ob: WartezimmerListe)
   {
      result.push_back(ob.getAnzahlPlaetze());
   }
   return result
}
```

Comment: ok I have done it with your vector idea. There is only one error, because it cannot access the "WartezimmerListe". How can I make it? Something like vector<Wartezimmer>::Station getWartezimmer() ?? It must have to do something with the class, because otherwise it cannot access the list

Comment: I have changed to vector<Wartezimmer> Station::getWartezimmer(). Earlier it was based on that if you would leave the implementation inside of the class not outside of

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working exactly as it should work, the function `getWartezimmer()` returns something as soon as it finds it.

In this code

```
int Station::getWartezimmer(){
  list<Wartezimmer>::iterator I;
  for (i = WartezimmerListe.begin(); i != WartezimmerListe.end(); i++){
    
  return  i->getAnzahlPlaetze(); //--> this line
  }

  return 0;
};
```

at the lined I've marked, the function `getAnzahlPlaetze()` fetches a value and returns it to a returns statement. What happens then? the return statement returns this value to the main function and the execution continues from there. So every time you call this function, it will always return the firs value of the `WartezimmerListe` vector.

I don't know the exact behavior that you are looking for after calling `getWartezimmer()`. do you wanna pop an element from the beginning of the array or from its end?

You can edit the `getAnzahlPlaetze()` function to return an element and then delete it or use [std::vector::pop_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) if it matches your needs. This will effectively give you a new value for each call.

If you want to maintain the original vector but also poping values from it you can define a static variable inside the class and use it to index the vector.

I don't think you want `getAnzahlPlaetze()` to return the whole values of the vector because it makes no sense. You can use the vector itself.